# Is there any way to search variable values in Visual Studio 2010's debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Suppose I'm running a huge C++ project in Microsoft Visual Studio. I have the debugger connected and it hits a breakpoint. Is there any way to search all variables in the project to see if, say, there is an int variable with a value of 62?

Comment: I'd find this highly unlikely. The debugger only sees variables that are currently in scope, and to view others it has to step back through the call stack to restore content. Why in the world would you need to do this anyway? This sounds very much like an XY problem to me. I've been writing code and stepping through it in debuggers for close to three decades now, and never once had the need to do what you're asking.

Comment: To expand on @KenWhite's comment, "What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?"  Looking for any int in the program's storage that contains 62 sounds suspiciously to me like it's part of trying to solve a larger problem.  Let us know what that larger problem is, maybe there's another way to attack it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately, there is **no way to search directly** for values of variables in Visual Studio 2010's debugger, only check their values by way of logging it or dumping program memory.

I assume you're looking for a feature that's like the one included in VS2015's C#.NET debugger, where you can see the values of all variables in real time, however this isn't an included feature for any C++ debugger that I know of.

It sounds like your issue can instead be solved by routinely checking the value of variables throughout your code, either by using simple printouts, or looking at raw RAM after dumping, if you're really insistent on not putting in logging. If none of this solves your issue, start a new question with the problem you're trying to solve with this question.